# modalDialogBox parameters and ie issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

In modaldialogBox when use the dialogHeight and dialogWidth the size of the dialogbox is not increased in IE.

I want to disable the scroll bar in the modaldialogbox and display as whole page and want to remove the address bar of modaldialogbox in IE.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about jQuery???  PHP does not have anything like a "modalDialogBox" natively...  Or are you referring to opening a new window?

PHP is server side code that only interacts with a client browser by sending it HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.  PHP itself will not be able to create a modal dialog box for you.

I know that in C# there is an object/class like you describe, but that is only for desktop applications -- it does not carry over to ASP.net with C# as "code behind."

Hopefully this helps your research... feel free to post back here if you have further questions.

Cheers!

h

Comment: Html and javascript .Found the solution for increasing height and width of modaldialogbox. the mistake is missed the second arugument    <html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
function openWindow() {

   window.showModalDialog("http://www.google.com"," ","dialogHeight:1500;dialogWidth:1500");
} 
</script>
<body>
<button onclick="openWindow();">Red</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: But now needed to Disable or Hide the address Bar

Comment: @Maha.8622 your welcome, I'm glad you figured it out :)  upvote me? :D